# Scanning For a Service on Online Devices with Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

I wrote a script to tell me if the SEP Master Service is running for all computer listed in a file, start the service if its stopped, and let me know if it doesn't exist. It's working, but when the script hits a computer that is not online, it slows down until an error is returned and then finally goes to the next computer in the list. Is there a way to only scan for the service on the deivces in the list that are online and can be pinged on the network?

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp2\ComputerList.txt"
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
   $service = Get-Service -name SepMasterService -computername $computer
   $ServiceStatus = $service.Status
   $ServiceDisplayName = $service.DisplayName

   if ($ServiceStatus -eq 'Running') {
      Write-Output "Service OK - Status of $ServiceDisplayName is $ServiceStatus on $computer"
   }
   elseif ($ServiceStatus -eq 'stopped') {
      Start-Service -Name SepMasterService -PassThru
   }
   else {
      Write-Output "Symantec Endpoint Protection doesn't exist on $computer"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a check for online machines using the test-connection cmdlet and go to the next computer.

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp2\ComputerList.txt"
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    if(!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet))
    {
        Write-Output "$computer is offline"
        continue
    }
   $service = Get-Service -name SepMasterService -computername $computer
   $ServiceStatus = $service.Status
   $ServiceDisplayName = $service.DisplayName

   if ($ServiceStatus -eq 'Running') {
      Write-Output "Service OK - Status of $ServiceDisplayName is $ServiceStatus on $computer"
   }
   elseif ($ServiceStatus -eq 'stopped') {
      Start-Service -Name SepMasterService -PassThru
   }
   else {
      Write-Output "Symantec Endpoint Protection doesn't exist on $computer"
   }
}
```

The `-Count` parameter specifies how many time to ping the computer.  The default is 4 but this will speed up your process.  The continue statement will stop executing any of the code in the current iteration of the foreach loop and go to the next computer.

Hope this helps.